# Code generation for composition using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance, oop, composition

[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), along with other sources suggest that  we should consider using [composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). I have often found my self achieving such composition by using the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and implementing forwarding methods that delegate invocations to a wrapped object.

However, I often find myself writing many simple forwarding methods of the type:

```
public void myMethod(String name) {
    instance.myMethod(name);
}
```

Is there anyway of auto-generating these forwarding methods within Eclipse (3.4.x)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Source menu choose "Generate Delegate Methods".  It will give you a list of methods available on any of your fields that you can have the current object forward to.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom template (Window > Preferences > filter on "Template") that has a placeholder for the method name and parameter name.